# Unable to Attach Debug Visual Studio 2017 with VB .NET got Error Exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.ExceptionCollection' was thrown

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I am trying to fix an error I got:

> **The designer loader did not provide a root component but has not indicated why.**

And then when I close and re-open I get this error:

> **Exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.ExceptionCollection' was thrown.**

I am trying to follow this answer:
[System.ComponentModel.Design.ExceptionCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579544/system-componentmodel-design-exceptioncollection)

1. I cant find:

> In one instance, goto Debug->Exceptions and enable all the 'Thrown'
> options to stop at first chance exceptions

So I went to Debug>Windows>Exception Settings. But I was not certain what to check since there is no 'Thrown' that seems to make sense. Maybe check everything?

1. I can't attach to the process it is missing when I tried to do this:

   In the same instance, select Debug->Attach to Process, select devenv.exe.
   [image]

This is what I got when I debugged it with  Jimi's suggestions:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu7nl.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLyJm.png

The form works fine at run time, it only has an issue at design time.

Comment: [Walkthrough: Debug Custom Windows Forms Controls at Design Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-debugging-custom-windows-forms-controls-at-design-time)

Comment: Before you start another debug session for nothing, do a Clean-Solution, Rebuild-Solution (not the Project, the Solution), close VS, go to your Solution's folder and delete the `\[Solution]\[Project]\Obj` folder (just the `Obj` folder :). Depending on the VS version, also the (Hidden) `.vs` folder you can find one level down the main Solution folder. If a Control, for some reason, is possibly using run-time values at design-time (thus, non initialized\null values\objects), see: [Error when opening User Control / Form with Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3621903/7444103).

Comment: This is what I got when I debugged it with  Jimi's suggestions:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLyJm.png

Comment: Review the code in your control and use the [DesignMode property of the Component class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166226/detecting-design-mode-from-a-controls-constructor) to wrap your code that should run at runtime.

Comment: How can I find the line number of the error? I tried adding breakpoints but it does not hit them at design time.

Comment: The form works fine at run time, it only has an issue at design time.

Comment: Can you help with this.  6. I am not sure where to put this, I am getting an error.. The designer cannot process the code at line 45... . `Dim designMode As Boolean = (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode = System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with for a solution.

1. I checked my code into Git to save the design file (you can also
   manually save in notepad or save the code file for a backup).
2. I opened the code file and left it open to get past this error:
   Exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.ExceptionCollection'
   was thrown.
3. I double clicked the form (or you can right click on the code to
   view designer).
4. I got a new error that I could ignore to skip: The designer loader
   did not provide a root component but has not indicated why.
5. I had to then move something on the form so that the form would
   re-generate designer code. Otherwise the error would keep coming up.
6. EDIT: I am not sure where to put this, but it should work. I am still trying to fix this, but here is what I have so far. I found a line of code causing issues. So I am going to use this to
   only run at runtime. `Dim designMode As Boolean = (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode = System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)`

BAM! Fixed :)  Thanks for all your help guys!